# Getting "git email is not registered", while executing "git push" with Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, paramiko, fabric

I want to know why it is throwing

> git email is not registered

when I'm trying to execute

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

command using paramiko/Fabric.

Even I've tried

```
git config --global user.email a@a.com
```

```
git commit --no-edit --rest-author
```

```
git push origin HEAD:refs/for/master
```

All are throwing the same.

But the same commands are working fine when I try locally in terminal.